# How can I reproduce this image in a simple way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, pspicture

I need to draw this simple scheme in latex, how would you do it in a simple way ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a start (and not an attempt to reproduce your screen shot, which is hard to read). You can use the `patterns.meta` library for the pattern, `decorations.markings` for the `+` signs on the boundaries, and a smooth cycle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,patterns.meta}
\tikzset{plus marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
 mark=between positions 0 and 1-1/#1 step 1/#1 with {\node[blue]{$+$};}}},
 plus marks/.default=5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\colorlet{dgreen}{green!60!black}
\begin{scope}
 \draw[plus marks=16,pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={5pt}]}] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
 \draw[fill=white,draw=red!20,thick]  plot[smooth cycle,looseness=1.3] coordinates 
 {(1.2,1.2) (2.5,1.3) (3.6,1.5) (3.7,2.2)
 (3,3.2) (1.6,2.9) };
 \path(2.5,2) node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,text=dgreen,
    label={[blue]above:$+$},
    label={[blue]left:$+$}]{$-$};
\end{scope} 
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
 \draw[plus marks=16,pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={5pt}]}] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
 \draw[fill=white,draw=red!20,thick]  plot[smooth cycle,looseness=1.3] coordinates 
 {(1.2,1.2) (2.5,1.3) (3.6,1.5) (3.7,2.2)
 (3,3.2) (1.6,2.9) };
 \path(2.5,2) node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,text=blue,
    label={[dgreen]above:$+$},
    label={[dgreen]left:$+$}]{$+$};
\end{scope} 
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm]
 \draw[plus marks=16] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is a great starting point, I need only to increase the thickness of the plus signa and add some captions. Thanks